# Как в pycharm получить curl своего тестового запроса

Tags: python, curl, pycharm

У меня есть автотест, который формирует запрос на сервер. Я могу получить ответ на свой запрос используя обычный print, но как мне увидеть curl своего запроса?

Искал инфу в интернете, так ничего и не нашел..

Comment: Руками написать...